# Non-standard question about random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I am not sure which subbranch of mathematics this is, so I cannot give a precise tag. I am doing research, and this suddenly popped out of no where. So, please hear me out.

---

$x$ is a variable that takes on random values. $x$ is said to 'stable' if $|x| \leq 1$.

Here is an example: $x = \dfrac{cY+1}{2}$, where $Y \sim U(0,2)$. In this case, $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $Y$ is a random variable. For what value of $c$ will $x$ become 'stable'?

Since we know that $\dfrac{1}{2}cY \sim U(0, c)$, then $\dfrac{1}{2}cY + \dfrac{1}{2} \sim U(\frac{1}{2}, c+\frac{1}{2})$. We want $x$ to be stable so $|c+\frac{1}{2}| \leq 1$, therefore, $c \in [-\frac{3}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]$.

---

Here is my question:

Let $Y \sim U(0,1)$. For what value of $c$ will make $x$ 'stable' if

$$x = \dfrac{\sqrt{(Y-\frac{2}{c})^2-4}}{2}?$$

Comment: Note that $|x|<1$ is the same event as $x^2<1\implies |Y-2/c|<2\sqrt{2}$. Can you proceed now?

Comment: right. thanks. I would like to ask if this is from a specific theme/part/topic in probability? So I would be able to get the correct keywords to search.

Comment: A random variable $X$ is said to have stable distribution if a linear combination of its independent copies has the same distribution as $X$ except from some possible scaling. See the definition [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution).

Comment: I'm not sure if the 'stable' I am referring to is similar to the stable distribution that you are posting in the link above. They seem different to me. And I am not totally sure what to call the condition $|x| \leq 1$, hnce the name 'stable' in quotations. It seems intuitive for me to call it by its current name. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think the stable you are referring to should be correctly called bounded (w.p. 1). This kind of condition arises in [Bounded Convergence Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem), for example.

Answer (score 1):

You want to find $c$ such that $$-1\le \dfrac{\sqrt{(Y-2/c)^2-4}}{2} \le 1$$ (and in particular is real) for $0 \le Y \le 1$.  Equivalently,
$$ 4 \le (Y - 2/c)^2  \le 8$$
for $0 \le Y \le 1$.  So either $2 \le Y - 2/c \le 2 \sqrt{2}$ in that interval, or $-2\sqrt{2} \le Y - 2/c \le -2$.  Now unfortunately, 
$2\sqrt{2} - 2 < 1$, so this can't ever be true for all $Y \in [0,1]$.

EDIT: If complex numbers are acceptable, then you just need $0 \le (Y - 2/c)^2 \le 8$, so $-2\sqrt{2} \le Y - 2/c \le 2 \sqrt{2}$ for $0 \le Y \le 1$, and thus either  $c \ge \sqrt{2}/2$ or $c \le -(2 + 4 \sqrt{2})/7$.

Comment: I plugged in 1 and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. They seem to work?

Comment: Are you requiring $x$ to be real?  For example, if $Y - 2/c = 0$, is $x = \sqrt{-4}/2 = i$ acceptable?

Comment: I wasn't able to think about that earlier. Yeah, I guess complex numbers are acceptable, and $|x|$ would be absolute value for real values and norms for complex numbers.